# Nginx rewrite rule for query string

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am looking for a Nginx rewrite rule to rewrite (handling relative paths) e.g.

```
domain.com/en/?var1=val1&var2=val2
```

to

```
domain.com/?var1=val1&var2=val2
```

Which is not simply removing the language code 'en' from the URL, because there are other pages like:

```
domain.com/en/page1
```

which should not be rewritten to

```
domain.com/page1
```

So only removing when there is a query string in the URL. I have already tried:

```
rewrite ^/en/?s=(.*) /$args
```